# How to Pass dynamic value to Sql by using WSO2

Tags: wso2, db2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

My requirement is to Pass the Dynamic Values , I just Hard coded the values for time being, Could any one help it out. Thanks in advance.(db2 database)

select sname from student where sname like ('%abc123%');

It is Picking the Values as expected. But i just hard coded it in DSS, How to pass it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Example service would like below,

```
<data name="dssTest" transports="http https local">              
  <config enableOData="false" id="TestDB">
    <property name="driverClassName">...</property>
    <property name="url">...</property>
    <property name="username">...</property>
    <property name="password">...</property>
  </config>
  <query id="testQuery" useConfig="TestDB">
    <sql>Select sname from student where sname like CONCAT('%', :whereclause, '%')</sql>
    <result element="StudentData" rowName="Student">
      <element column="snumber" name="snumber" optional="true" xsdType="string"/>
      <element column="sname" name="sname" optional="true" xsdType="string"/>
    </result>
    <param name="whereclause" sqlType="QUERY_STRING"/>
  </query>
  <operation name="testQueryOp">
    <call-query href="testQuery">
      <with-param name="whereclause" query-param="whereclause"/>
    </call-query>
  </operation>
</data>
```

When calling this service you can send in a value for where clause.

```
<body>                                                                  
  <p:testQueryOp xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <p:whereclause>abc123</p:whereclause>
  </p:testQueryOp>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Saad Bro for Response, But i could not able to execute throwing the following error {
   "rootCause": null,
   "category": "EISBackendException",
   "message": "DSS Service call failed for operation: getSname",
   "timestamp": "2018-06-27T18:00:37+0530"
}


Backend log:
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=428
84, SQLERRMC=CONCAT;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.57.110
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:- Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try changing the sqlType to STRING from QUERY_STRING 
<param name="whereclause" sqlType="STRING"/>

Comment: Tried with "String" ,"Query-String", throwing the error :) 
[2018-06-27 17:55:55,470] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver} -  Error in in-out message receiver
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRM
C=CONCAT;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.57.110
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:- Could you please :)

Comment: I didn't know its db2 database. Can you try changing the query as below,
Select sname from student where sname like CONCAT(CONCAT('%',':whereclause'),'%')

whereclause sqlType should be STRING

Comment: How is this safe? You're passing SQL as an HTTP parameter. How do you defend against SQL injection attacks with this method? It's also not very practical to have the client craft SQL to send to the query. I guess this is only viable if you have some ESB sitting in front of the query, but even then it's messy.